# Object extraction for a low contrast image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, text-extraction

I have an image with very low contrast, from which I would like to extract a text object. Since it has a low contrast, I tried a few methods but no method gave me a satisfying result. I used `watershed` to extract the text object, but as the contrast is poor the extraction was not successful.

My program for `watershed` is:

```
I_cropped=imread(strcat('C:\Id\',currentfilename));
I_cropped = rgb2gray(I_cropped);
I_eq = histeq(I_cropped);  
figure,imshow(I_eq);
bw = im2bw(I_eq, graythresh(I_eq));
bw2 = imfill(bw,'holes');
bw3 = imopen(bw2, ones(5,5));
bw4 = bwareaopen(bw3, 40);
bw = im2bw(I_eq, graythresh(I_eq));
figure,imshow(bw);
mask_em = imextendedmax(I_eq, 30);
mask_em = imclose(mask_em, ones(5,5));
mask_em = imfill(mask_em, 'holes');
mask_em = bwareaopen(mask_em, 40);
figure,imshow(mask_em);
I_eq_c = imcomplement(I_eq);
figure,imshow(I_eq_c);
I_mod = imimposemin(I_eq_c, ~bw4 | mask_em);
figure,imshow(I_mod);
L = watershed(I_mod);
figure,imshow(label2rgb(L));
```

I applied `laplacian` filter and to enhance edge, but it was not effective.

My objective is to extract text object. What method should I try for such low contrast image?

The image is attached:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "_extract text object_" ? You want to get a region with all the digits, separate the digits, or get a number corresponding to the number on the image ? Please be more specific on the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

First apply a median filter with a large kernel on the image to remove outliers and then apply a threshold to convert to a binary image. Note that playing with the kernel size of the filter alters the threshold level you need to use. Play around with it to see the output changing.

Then invert the image and apply `regionprops` to detect objects in the image. After that a little math to deduce the x and y origin (defining upper left corner) as well as the width and length of the large bounding box enclosing all the letters from the image.

Here is the code:

```
clear
clc

close all

Im = rgb2gray(imread('Imtext.png'));

%// Apply median filter to remove outliers
Im = medfilt2(Im,[9 9]);

%// Clear borders and apply threshold, then invert image
ImBW = imclearborder(~(im2bw(Im,.55)));

%// Find bounding boxes to delineate text regions.
S = regionprops(ImBW,'BoundingBox');

%// Concatenate all bounding boxes and obtain x,y, width and length of big
%// bounding box enclosing everything
bb = cat(1,S.BoundingBox);

LargeBB_x = min(bb(:,1));
LargeBB_y = min(bb(:,2));

LargeBB_height = max(bb(:,4));

%// Find last column in which pixel value is 1; that's the end 
%// of the bounding box.
[~,ic] = find(ImBW==1);
MaxCol = max(ic(:));

LargeBB_width = MaxCol-LargeBB_x;

%// Display boxes
imshow(ImBW)
hold on
    rectangle('Position',[LargeBB_x LargeBB_y LargeBB_width LargeBB_height],'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2) 

hold off
```

And the output:

[image]

Or with the original image:

[image]

Comment: awesome! Good luck :)

Comment: Is there a way I can further segment individual digit?

Comment: Mhh you could apply image erosion or other morphological operations to thin the letters...look into `bwmorph` and `imerode`.